# Retopoflow - How to only do a portion of the mesh?

Tags: retopology

I have a model that needs Retopology in portion of the mesh only. What I'd like to do is use Retopoflow to do the Retopology in that area but then have Retopoflow copy the rest of the poly's of the model into place so I don't have to do the whole thing. Is this possible?